# Android gradle: How do I get the merged resources directory in the build.gradle script?

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

The code in question looks like

```
applicationVariants.all{ variant ->
   if(variant.buildType.name == 'test'){
      println 'path res: ' + //need directory path here
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
variant.mergeResourcesProvider.get().outputDir.get()
```

seems to return the path I needed. Likewise for mergeAssetsProvider